# iptables on Ubuntu18.04 doesn't filter when changing default-action to DROP

Tags: networking, iptables, ubuntu-18.04, ports

I am facing a issue on a freshly set up Server in the Hetzner-Cloud running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

After installing Iptables(-persistent) and configuring the following ruleset:

```
root@inetsec:/home/linus# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             1.2.3.4         tcp dpt:272

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I still can get a successful TCP-Handshake using Telnet, using several other Ports (110, 143, 25, 993).

Even so, the Applications that are responsible for this ports (Dovecot & Postfix) are not even running, and `netstat -tulpen` shows:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode      PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      112        20485      1198/mysqld         
tcp        0      0 1.2.3.4:272             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          18773      1047/sshd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      101        19746      1113/systemd-resolv 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      111        19076      1004/named          
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           101        19745      1113/systemd-resolv 
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           111        19075      1004/named          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           0          18955      1173/dhclient       
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           0          15042      816/dhclient
```

, I still get a TCP-Handshake on the mentioned Ports using telnet, instead of the expected Timeout (due to INPUT DROP-Policy) or at least a `ICMP-Destination Unreachable (3)` Message for the closed Ports.

A issue I found is, that if I am rebooting the sever with saved iptable ruleset (`iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4`) the Server hangs around 5 minutes in state

```
....
iscsi: registered transport (tcp)
iscsi: registered transport (user)
```

before enabling login.

Also it then takes around 15 seconds to execute the command `iptables -L`

Comment: Do you mean you can get a successful handshake when connecting from outside _to_ this system?

Comment: Correct, I checked it with 2 different outbreaks on 2 different providers.

Comment: Using tcpdump (server) and wireshark (client) I found out, that the Filter works as expected, drops the packets and doesn't send a response.

Comment: The strange thing is, that telnet and nmap both show the ports open, even if they aren't. Maybe that is a bug in correlation with the OSX 10.15 update, I recently did.

It still doesn't explain why the output of ```iptables -L``` takes 10 seconds, if the default action for INPUT is set to DROP instead of ACCEPT...

Comment: Well, iptables by default makes DNS queries and you're blocking the responses, so it waits a long time for them to (not) arrive... What kind of ISP are you using? Are the TCP SYN packets actually arriving at your 'server'? Could it be that your modem is spoofing responses (as e.g. satellite modems apparently do)?

Comment: Hi @grawity you were absolutely right, whenever I add -n it works. I had configured 127.0.0.53 in my ```resolve.conf```